# Css list issue, something over top of my list?

Tags: html, css, list, background-image

I have this site here http://jamessuske.com/freelance/seasons/

and at the bottom you will a social media list, but as you can see it looks messy and it looks like something is over top of it. I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Here is my CSS:

```
ul.social-media{
    margin-left:20px;
    padding-top:30px;
}

ul.social-media li{
    float:left;
    padding-left:5px;
}

ul.social-media li.twitter{
    background-image:url(http://jamessuske.com/freelance/seasons/images/social.png);
    background-position-x:0px;
    width:25px;
    height:26px;
}

ul.social-media li.instagram{
    background-image:url(http://jamessuske.com/freelance/seasons/images/social.png);
    background-position-x:-26px;
    width:25px;
    height:26px;
}

ul.social-media li.facebook{
    background-image:url(http://jamessuske.com/freelance/seasons/images/social.png);
    background-position-x:-52px;
    width:25px;
    height:26px;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<ul class="social-media">
<li class="twitter"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
<li class="instagram"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
<li class="facebook"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `list-style:none;` to `ul.social-media li` class

Comment: in ul tag of social media add `style="list-style-type:none"` I found this while trying. This also works.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question well, so as my understanding  - 
Please try `margin-top: 0px;` with your `ul.social-media` CSS.

Try this -

```
ul.social-media{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top:30px;
}
```

You can see into `Chrome Development Tool`, your `<ul>` take `margin-top: 16px;` througt inherited style. So you need to set `margin-top: 0px;` for this work

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATES:** I got it.  It seems you're **not removing the bullets of ul.**  That the problem.

```
list-style-type: none;
```

so this

```
ul.social-media {
margin-left: 20px;
padding-top: 30px;
list-style-type: none;
}
```